# custom tile in app launcher not showing up

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

My scenario  : i have created a new custom tile in office 365 but its doesn't show up for any of the users including me(global admin). I have check that each user has an exchange mail box and has use the mailbox at least once and still it doesn't work.

Note: i did make sure that the picture used for custom tile is access via an anonymous link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload the icon to the Site Assets Library. Essentially, it needs to reside in a site/library that is accessible by everyone.

After the Office 365 Administrator add a custom icon/tile to Office 365 apps, it is available for individual users to add (pin) to their own App Launchers. This is a mandatory step and must be performed by each user individually.

Refer to the following article about Hhow to add a custom Tile to Office 365 App Launcher step by step:

https://sharepointmaven.com/add-custom-tile-office-365-app-launcher/